Is "Tom sings well, which his brother doesn't" natural?

Tom sings well, which his brother doesn't.

The usage of 'which' seems like a commentary:

WM: This morning we have the monthly jobs report, which who knows if it
will meet or beat expectations.

Is this sentence natural? Can we use 'but' rather than 'which'?

MW does label that usage as informal. Standard English would omit the which and begin a new sentence with "Who knows..."

Definitely doesn't sound natural. "but" is fine, or a new sentence as per Kate's comment.

As timchessish says "but" works well. So does "whilst". Altering the meaning somewhat you could also say "sadly" or "unfortunately"

I'd say it's idiomatic in conversational American English.  Why did you invite him to your poker night but not me? -- Because he gambles big, which you don't.

But your singing example is not the same as the M-W one.  In the M-W example, which has an antecedent noun, "report".

In the sense that it can be heard from native speakers, it's natural. But it's the sort of construction that native speakers agree is ungrammatical when their attention is drawn to it. Older and better-educated speakers rarely employ it, but I wouldn't say they never do. Anecdotally, I find that the relative pronouns are in flux in English. (The major example is the disappearance of "who" in favour of "that".)

'Tom sings well, which his brother doesn't' isn't strictly ungrammatical but that's as good as it gets.
Is it natural? No.
Is it colloquial or idiomatic? No.

'Which' is supposed to introduce non-defining clauses, ie information about the subject that is not essential (for example "Tom sings well, which is nice" adds an opinion that is interesting but not necessary). Defining clauses, which contain essential information about the subject, are supposed to be introduced with 'that' (for example "Tom sings songs that he writes himself" tells us something important that defines the songs he sings). However, language evolves, and many modern dictionaries acknowledge that 'which' can be used to introduce either kind of clause. But whether the clause introduced is defining or non-defining, it has to say something about the subject of the sentence.
In your example, the subject appears to be Tom, but the 'which' clause doesn't tell us anything about him, it is about his brother, so it doesn't feel right.
If the purpose is to draw a distinction between the two brothers, by comparing their singing abilities, it is more natural to say something like:

Tom sings well but his brother doesn't.
Tom sings well while his brother does not.
Tom sings well although his brother does not.

